# Running into an issue with scraping using cheeriojs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape the article links from a website and am running into an issue where only one link is scraped and the other elements are not looped over.  I'm using nodejs with the cheerio and request packages.

```
    request('http://www.nj.com/politics', function(error, response, html) {

    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var results = [];

    $('#river-container ul').each(function(i, element) {

        var articleLink = $(element).find('li.river-item.has-photo').find('div.item-text').find('h2.h2.fullheadline').find('a').attr('href');
        results.push({ link: articleLink });
    });

    res.send(results);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML you show only has one element that matches the selector `#river-container ul` so your `.each()` only has one iteration through the loop.  If you want to iterate all the `<li>` entries beneath the `<ul>`, then change your outer loop to:

```
$('#river-container ul li').each(...)
```

And, then modify the inner `.find()` statements to adjust to the fact that you've already matched the `<li>`.

Or, change the top selector to be what you really want:

```
request('http://www.nj.com/politics', function(error, response, html) {

    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var results = [];

    $('#river-container ul li.river-item.has-photo div.item-text h2.h2.fullheadline a').each(function(i, element) {

        var articleLink = $(element).attr('href');
        results.push({ link: articleLink });
    });

    res.send(results);

});
```

Comment: @JayPatel - See the additional edit to my question.  I think you can put all your `.find()` statements into just one selector.

Comment: @JayPatel - Also, since it looks like you may be new here, if this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure.